# "Inline parts" in exam class like inlineitem

Tags: enumitem, exam

Producing exams with exam class, I want to know if there is a command like `\inlineitem`, for parts, where I can write parts of a question in the same line, something like `\part`, `\inlinepart`. Let me kindly remark that I want to "inline" the environment part, because I use it in my exercises with the option `addpoints`, where the parts are given as in the MWE, `\part[2]` and `\part[3]`, and the option uses the points given into brackets to produce gradetable and so...  I give the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}   % The option inline enables "inline" itemizing
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\inlineitem}[1][]{%
\ifnum\enit@type=\tw@
    {\descriptionlabel{#1}}
  \hspace{\labelsep}%
\else
  \ifnum\enit@type=\z@
       \refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi
    \quad\@itemlabel\nobreakspace\hspace{\labelsep}%
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question 
\begin{parts}
\part[2] First part
\part[3] Second part
\end{parts}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\inlineitem Second item
\end{enumerate}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

and the file produced,

[image]

Comment: You may want to take a look at the `tasks` package

Comment: I have read the doc of the package, which is of interest, but I want to re-use the environment `parts` in my files, and I think that the package doesn't enable to renew defined environments... I gave a more explanation of my goal in the edit of my question. Thank you